# Editing draggable after it's added to a sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

Hey, I'm trying to work out what event I need to bind to and what property I need to use to get a reference to the DOM element for the dropped item (That is the item in the receiving list.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<ul id="toolbox">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
<ul id="existing">
</ul>
<script language="javascript">
    $('#existing').sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $('#toolbox li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#existing',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
    });
</script>
```

My objective is to turn, for example, A into something else once it's dropped into the #existing ul (Anything else will suffice - the real implementation is far more complex. I just need to get my hands on that DOM element).

I have tried the following as the receive for my sortable:

```
function receive(ev, ui)
{
    $(this).append('<b>this</b>');
    ui.sender.append('<b>sender</b>');
    ui.item.append('<b>item</b>');
}
```

But this appears to be the #existing UL, sender and item are both the li that was dragged in toolbox. What I'm looking for is the newly created li inside #existing. Is there a property or another event which will give me what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue.  I solved it with the following:

```
$('#existing').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        // ui.draggable is the node that gets created in #existing
        // ui.draggable[0].originDragger is the node that was 
        // dragged from #toolbox
    }
}).sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, I didn't realize you could stack a droppable on the sortable to get the extra events. I ended up taking a different tact in the end by putting a CSS class on the source that I could detect and remove once it moved over, but this is a cleaner answer and I'll probably look towards implementing this instead if I have time.

Comment: Hi Justin, this is an interesting combination, yet in my case "drop" is called twice - I think both for drop into the sortable, and for the drop in the sortable itself. Do you experience the same? You can see this on this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/NPC42/8JVrp/4/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried either of these, but in theory, they seem like they would work. First, if you made the `ul#existing` also a [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/), you could do something on the `drop` event, such as get the info you need from that li, like it's `text()`, remove that object from the DOM and generate a new element.

Orrr, you could do something on the `stop` event of your draggable, like check whether the elements parents are now `ul#existing`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do not bind to `sortreceive`, instead bind to `sortout` like so

```
$("#sortable").bind('sortout', function(event, ui) {
 console.log(ui.item);
});
```

**OR**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({ //during initialization
  out:function(event, ui) {
     console.log(ui.item);
   }
 });
```

in this case `ui.item` will be the element you are looking for

Comment: SortOut is when something leaves a sortable. I assume you're meaning to bind it to the other sortable, but in this case the other side is only a draggable (And intentionally not a sortable) so this won't work. Thanks though.